# SQL - decrease value to zero

Tags: mysql, sql

I know how to increase/decrease value in column.

value type is `INT(11)`

Command:

```
UPDATE table SET value = value - 1 WHERE id = 1
```

But when value reaches "0" it keeps decreasing.

**Question:** How to decrease until zero, so I don't get value (-1) in column?

Thank you for your code / ideas / suggestions

Comment: `UPDATE table SET value = value - 1 WHERE id = 1 AND value > 0`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use a conditional:

```
UPDATE table
    SET value = value - 1
    WHERE id = 1 AND value > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the where clause:

```
UPDATE table SET value = value - 1 WHERE (id = 1) AND (value > 0)
```

Once value reaches 0, it won't get updated anymore, because the `where` clause will exclude that record from the update.

Answer (score 0):

You can add on to your where clause like so:

```
UPDATE table 
SET value = value - 1 
WHERE id = 1 and value >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html).

```
UPDATE table SET value = CASE WHEN value = 1 THEN value = value - 1
ELSE value
END
WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: `CASE` might be a bad choice, since if you got `INDEX` on column `value`, it is likely that less rows will be returned, less rows will be updated = much less I/Os = better performance